# Exit status of `read` is 1 even though it appears to be succeeding

Tags: bash

```
read -r -d '' TMP <<<'hello'
```

successfully writes "hello" to `$TMP`, yet the exit status is `1`.

Is this expected/intended? Should I just put `!` at the start of that line to invert the exit code if I want to to succeed when it succeeds?

---

N.B. the above example is simplified. Here's the full thing:

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' SLACK_PAYLOAD <<'JSON'
{
    "channel": $channel,
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": $message
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": $changelog
            }
        }
    ]
}
JSON
```

I'm mostly using `read` because I want multiple lines.

---

To be even more clear, my script is using

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -eio pipefail
```

It appears there are some subtle differences with `zsh` which I'm not really opposed to (I use it as my shell but not for scripts), but my script is already written for bash.

Comment: Help for Bash built-ins is available via `help <cmd>`: `help read`. Plus `man bash` covers them.

Comment: `-d ''` says there's expected to be a NUL terminating the input record. The temporary input file created by `<<<'hello'` has no NUL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` expects the line to end with the configured delimiter and errors out if it's missing. You can see this even when not using `-d` if you have it read input that's missing the usual newline at EOF.

How can we pass input without it? Well, `<<<` automatically adds a newline, so that won't work. We can omit it by using

- `printf`, which doesn't add newlines the way `<<<` (or `echo`) does; and
- [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to pass `printf`'s output to `read` without creating a subshell. If we used a pipeline like `printf | read` then `read` would run in a subshell and the parent shell wouldn't see the assignment to `TMP`.

That looks like:

```
bash❯ read -r TMP < <(printf 'hello')
bash❯ echo $?
1
```

Now when you use `-d ''`, `read` looks for a `\0` (NUL character) delimiter. Of course there is no `\0` at the end of `'hello'`. So let's add one! If we do then it succeeds:

```
bash❯ read -r -d '' TMP < <(printf 'hello')
bash❯ echo $?
1
bash❯ read -r -d '' TMP < <(printf 'hello\0')
bash❯ echo $?
0
```

Interestingly, in zsh process substitution isn't needed:

```
zsh❯ read -r -d '' TMP <<< $'hello'
zsh❯ echo $?
1
zsh❯ read -r -d '' TMP <<< $'hello\0'
zsh❯ echo $?
0
```

---

If your intention is to set a variable to a large multiline string there's no need for `read`. Strings can span multiple lines:

```
SLACK_PAYLOAD='
{
    "channel": $channel,
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": $message
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": $changelog
            }
        }
    ]
}
')
```

Or if you like the heredoc syntax, this version with `cat` would also work:

```
SLACK_PAYLOAD="$(cat <<'JSON'
{
    "channel": $channel,
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": $message
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": $changelog
            }
        }
    ]
}
JSON
)"
```

Comment: What about for multi-line strings? I'm using `read` because I want multiple lines and to avoid having to escape everything. `printf` unfortunately won't help with that

Comment: Thank you :-) I appreciate both parts of your answer. Nice to know how `read` actually works. The double quotes around `$(cat ... )` aren't actually needed are they? I know they're needed in shell args, but I thought for variable assignments like this they were redundant.

Comment: Yes, you're right, they're not necessary. Lately I've taken to the habit of including quotes even when they're not strictly needed. It makes it easier to tell people "always quote expansions" rather than "always quote expansions, except in variable assignments or `case` blocks or on the left-hand side of `[[` or..."

Comment: Do you have any idea why `<<< $'hello\0'` does not work under bash? After all, this also generates a NUL-terminated stdin.

Comment: I presume that bash uses C strings internally, which are not NUL safe. In C `"hello"` and `"hello\0"` are the same string. I'm actually surprised/impressed at zsh's behavior. I took a brief glance at its source code and saw calls to `strcpy` and `strlen`, so I'm not actually sure how it avoids the NUL trap bash falls into.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this expected/intended?

Yes.

> Exit Status:
> **The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered**, read times out
> (in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
> or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.

(from `read --help`, emphasis mine)

In your case, it seems like you don't need `read` at all, you could just do

```
TMP='hello'
```

Comment: To extend a bit *why* this is expected: it enable the canonical way to read from a file via `while read line; do ... done < file` (`IFS=` etc. best practices skipped in favour of readability).

Comment: It's worth underlying that "end-of-file is encountered" is the specific reason (from the list of possibilities quoted) for a nonzero exit status here. (If we didn't have the `-d ''` we would be encountering a newline and ending the `read` there, before getting to the EOF).

Comment: Ah.. my script is bash but my shell in zsh. zsh `read --help` just outputs `read: bad option: -h`. My actual use-case is more complicated than just "hello" (updated Q)